Визуализация данных (график) в IDE Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA
Отлаживаю приложение для Android/JDK8, среда разработки IntelliJ IDEA. В программе есть два больших одномерных массива. Для анализа этих данных нужна визуализация в виде графика в среде разработке (приложению эти данные не нужны). Пошел по пути создания модуля в проекте, кот. прямо в IDE будет открывать окошко с графиком (желательно в процессе отладки). Нашел, вроде, подходящих кандидатов, но что-то не хватает:
Kotlin Notebook – всё устраивает, но передача данных через файл или сеть;
Lets-Plot for Kotlin – вывод графика либо в файл-картинку, либо в окно браузера.
Знающие, подскажите, может  есть более простой путь решения этой задачи?
ЗЫ: вторую неделю курю инет, голова уже кругом :(

В плагинах для IDE поищите, возможно кто-то уже сделал что-то подобное. Если нет, пишите свой. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/developing-plugins.html
